# how to use getFrames in cocos2d-js?

Tags: cocos2d-js

i am new in cocos2d-js here, i just created this code:`

```
    var that = this;
    that._dice
    // add player
    // create sprite sheet
    cc.spriteFrameCache.addSpriteFrames(res.dice_plist);
    var spriteSheet = new cc.SpriteBatchNode(res.diceRed_png);
    that.addChild(spriteSheet, 2);


    // init runningAction
    var animFrames = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
        var str = "dieRed" + i + ".png";
        var frame = cc.spriteFrameCache.getSpriteFrame(str);
        animFrames.push(frame);
    }

    var animation = new cc.Animation(animFrames, 0.1);
    that.runningAction = new cc.Repeat.create(new cc.Animate(animation), Math.random()*10);


    var diceSprite = new cc.Sprite("#dieRed1.png");
    diceSprite.visible = true;
    console.log(this.getContentSize(diceSprite));
    diceSprite.runAction(this.runningAction);

    that._dice.push(diceSprite);
    var size = cc.winSize;
    spriteSheet.setPosition(size.width/6.5, size.height/1.20);
    spriteSheet.setAnchorPoint(0.5, 0.5);
    spriteSheet.addChild(diceSprite, 2);
    `
```

and i would like to use the getFrames() feature to return the array of ccanimation frames. i'm just thinking to get the information of which picture are being animated on the screen there, for example, if the `#dieRed1.png` is being animated or visible on the screen, it would show value or return value of 1. i have tried to googled around and cannot find any other clue there. if there is any better method, i would love to see that as well. sorry for the english anyway, a bit confused how to arrange the words. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so refering to
[the official docs](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/js/v3x/symbols/cc.Animation.html)

> {Array} **getFrames()**
>
> Returns the array of animation frames

Which means you can just do:

```
var frames = animation.getFrames();
```

To get the array. And then you'll receive an array of cc.AnimationFrame.
To get sprite link do:

```
var frame = frames[0];//cc.AnimationFrame
var spriteFrame = frame.getSpriteFrame(); //cc.SpriteFrame
var texture = spriteFrame.getTexture(); // cc.Texture
```

And the texture itself should have the `name` attribute which may do the job.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion there, it does the work~

Comment: you're welcome, the full documentation is available here: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/js/v3x/ - please use it when you get stuck, usually its helpful